# How to find Null values from Gridview Textbox [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I am trying to disable the textbox if the textbox value is null, but I don`t know where I am doing wrong the following is not working, kindly check and share your suggestion.

WebForm:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GROUP">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" commandargument="Now_cmd" runat="server" 
            value='<%# Eval("now") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Textbox2"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTIVITY">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" commandargument="after_cmd" value='<%# Eval("afteronehour") %>' runat="server" 
            ></asp:TextBox>
            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="Textbox3"></cc1:CalendarExtender>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            string value = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToString();

            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToString() == string.Empty)
            {

                e.Row.Cells[i].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Input:

```
2015-07-03 09:44:02.380     2015-07-04 09:44:02.380
2015-07-03 09:4`4:53.360    2015-07-04 09:44:53.360
2015-07-03 09:47:00.580     NULL
2015-07-03 09:47:00.580     2015-07-04 09:44:53.360
```

So I need to disable the check box for NULL values

Comment: Is there any `NullPointerException` you seen?

Comment: If `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` is null then `e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToString()` must throw exception

Comment: Or `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` may be contains `"null"` as string

Comment: M.NasserJavaid, I did not have any nullpointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the `TextBox` with the `DataSource` Columns not the *Cell* so you should be looking for Text in the TextBox not the Cell. Also you may use `FindControl` instead of looping through `GridView` Row.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      TextBox tb1= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox2");

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "now"))))
         tb1.Enabled = false; 

      TextBox tb2= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox3");
      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "afteronehour"))))
         tb2.Enabled = false; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Adil, NullreferenceException is coming

Comment: If FindControl returns null, that means you do not have any control with given id in the current row. Make sure you give the correct id

Comment: Adil, Please check my gridview coding, I have this control, I got no error if I try to use if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow), but entire column get disabled, I need to disable only specific cell if the textbox value is null

Comment: Adil, I tried this too but the entire column get disabled, But I need to disable particular null cell

Comment: It was my mistake, as on RowDataBound the value is not yet assigned and all TextBoxes will be empty, so we need to look or DataItem instead of TextBox in grid for null or empty value..

Comment: Superb Finally I got the solution, Thanks Adil

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `null` and `empty` strings with `IsNullOrEmpty()` method which will check if string is `null` or `empty`.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text))
{
  e.Row.Cells[i].Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int r = 0; r < GridView1.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[r].FindControl("TextBox2");

    TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[r].FindControl("TextBox3");

if(tb1.Text==null)
{
tb1.Enabled=false;
}
else
{
tb1.Enabled=true;
}
if(tb2.Text==null)
{
tb2.Enabled=false;
}
else
{
tb2.Enabled=true;
}

}
```